# Does the derivative of the largest eigenvalue and its associated eigenvector exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\boldsymbol{A}(t):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a **rank-deficient** Hermitian function-valued matrix (its entries are analytic functions). Furthermore let $\lambda_1(t)$ (which is a simple eigenvalue $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$) be the largest eigenvalue of $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$, and let $\mathbf{x}_1(t)$ be its associated normalized eigenvector, $||\mathbf{x}_1(t)||_2=1$. Do the derivatives of $\lambda_1(t)$ and $\mathbf{x}_1(t)$ exist for all $t$? Moreover, are they equal to

$\lambda_1'(t) = \mathbf{x}_1^{H}(t)\boldsymbol{A}'(t)\mathbf{x}_1(t)$,

and

$\mathbf{x}_1'(t)=(\lambda_1(t)\boldsymbol{I}(t)-\boldsymbol{A}(t))^+\boldsymbol{A}'(t)\mathbf{x}_1(t)$.

Where $()^H$ is the Hermitian transpose and $()^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. The largest eigenvalue is **unique** and **never crosses** the other eigenvalues.

Comment: The smoothness follows from the implicit function theorem in a straightforward way. Then computing the derivative is an exercise in algebra. And I don't think this question is suitable for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I can see that this is a trivial question to some, but I can not find it stated for the global case (not just valid in some neighborhood) in any reference? Do you know of a reference that states that it is valid globally, not just locally? Rellich's theorem is valid locally as far as I know. Is it (Rellich) also valid globally and for a rank deficient matrix?